# How to access database in cPanel from home computer

Tags: java, mysql

I have created a database in cpanel using MySQL® Database Wizard. I have created a java class to access the database. For remote access I've added my IP to Remote MySQL® allow section & I have also allowed all privileges to a specific username with a password. Keeping all that settings, from my home computer I still can not access the database. I am running this java application in NetBeans. As the errors say:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

The source code goes like this:

```
package remoteserverconnection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class RemoteServerConnection {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection conn = null;

   try
   {

       String url = "jdbc:mysql://domainIP:3306/DBNamne";
       Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url,"UserName","password");
       System.out.println ("Database connection established");
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();

   }
 }
}
```

Am I doing it in wrong way? Or is there any other way to connect that database from home pc?

Comment: This is off-topic as it's more network related then programming related. But can you make a tcp connection between your two computers on port 3306? Probably not and there is the issue.

Comment: I had tried with port 3389 which was open and it's still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your host (judging from cPanel in the title) has a firewall rule set up that may be blocking access. That's very likely the case if it's a shared host which is the sort of service that typically uses cPanel.